# How to find difference between two dates in jsp?

Tags: jsp, date, formatting

I have a date format like "MMMM dd, yyyy" and i am using `<fmt:formatDate value="${purchaseDate}" pattern="MMMM dd, yyyy"/>` and i have to compare this with the current date and check whether the purchase date is less than a year from current date or not?? Any suggestion how this can be done...

Comment: Define a [custom function](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html#wp77078)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you would have to resort to `scriptlets` `<% //... your code ... %>` in this case.

And if you go with `scriptlets` then it would be simple Java Data comparison as shown [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_handling_date.htm).
You can also create a method in a utility class with comparison logic and then call it from your JSP.

I personally don't prefer `scriptlets` in my JSP code, so:

1. I would normally do this logic inside a java class and set a flag in `request` and pass it on to JSP. But this depends on how much logic you would need to do after this simple comparison.
2. Or you can build a simple custom-tag to do the logic for you (might be an overkill!)

So, if you really need to go with comparing dates in JSP then I guess `scriptlets` would be the only way to go.

Hope this gives some food for thought.